# Table higlight row with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

my view is this:

```
@model EscuDes.ViewModels.EstudianteIndexData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Estudiantes";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EscuelaSelectList, "Escuela", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Escuela, Model.EscuelaSelectList, "Escuelas", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Director </label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Director" disabled="disabled">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GrupoSelectList, "Grupo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 " })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Grupo, Model.GrupoSelectList, "Grupos", new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpleadoSelectList, "Empleado", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Empleado, Model.EmpleadoSelectList, "Empleado", new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
<br />
<br />
<table id="tabla" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido P.</th>
            <th>Apellido M.</th>
            <th>Telefono</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Grupo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="records_table"></tbody>
</table>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Grupo").CascadingDropDown("#Escuela", "GrupoCascadingDDL",
            {
                type: 'post',
                promptText: "Grupos",
                postData: function () {
                    return { EscuelaID: $("#Escuela").val() };
                }
            });
            $("#Empleado").CascadingDropDown("#Grupo", "EmpleadoCascadingDDL",
           {
               type: 'post',
               promptText: "Empleado",
               postData: function () {
                   return { GrupoID: $("#Grupo").val() };
               }
           });
            $('#Empleado').change(function () {
                $("#Empleado").prop('selectedIndex', 1);
                $('#Empleado').blur();
            });
            $('#Grupo').change(function () {
                $.getJSON(
                    '@Url.Action("EstudiantesGrupo", "Estudiante")',
                    { GrupoID: $("#Grupo").val() },
                    function (response) {
                        $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                            $('<tr>').append(
                            $('<td>').text(item.ID),
                            $('<td>').text(item.Nombre),
                            $('<td>').text(item.Paterno),
                            $('<td>').text(item.Materno),
                            $('<td>').text(item.Telefono),
                            $('<td>').text(item.Estado),
$('<td>').text(item.GrupoID)).appendTo('#records_table');
                        });
                    });
               $('#Grupo').blur();
            });
            $('#Escuela').on('change', function () {
                $.getJSON(
                    '@Url.Action("DirectorLabel", "Estudiante")',
                    { EscuelaID: $(this).val() },
                    function (response) {
                        $('#Director').val(response);
                    });
            });
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabla tbody tr').click(function (e) {
            alert("Start...");
            if ($(this).hasClass('success')) {
                $(this).removeClass('success');
            } else {
                $('tbody tr.success').removeClass('success');
                $(this).addClass('success');
            }
            alert("Finish...");
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

/http://jsfiddle.net/2ku99pLc/9/

I've seen it working on other answers but not with my code since my table gets loaded after user select options on cascaded DDL. Im using bootstrap css and jquery 1.10.2.

What's the matter with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to wrap your code in `$(document).ready();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabla tbody tr').click(function (e) {
        alert("Start...");
        if ($(this).hasClass('success')) {
            $(this).removeClass('success');
        } else {
            $('tbody tr.success').removeClass('success');
            $(this).addClass('success');
        }
        alert("Finish...");
    });
  });
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ku99pLc/7/)

if you dynamically load table content so change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#tabla tbody tr',function (e) {
            alert("Start...");
            if ($(this).hasClass('success')) {
                $(this).removeClass('success');
            } else {
                $('tbody tr.success').removeClass('success');
                $(this).addClass('success');
            }
            alert("Finish...");
        });
      });
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ku99pLc/8/)

with dynamically content load  instead of using

```
$(element).click() ;
```

use

```
$(document).on('click','element',function(){});
```

Comment: ok you are right about that but my table load from a json and it doesn't work i'll update the question.

Comment: Pythonus  Good Luck :)